# Can we compare machine learning and Evolutionary algorithms?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm

Please guide me "Can we compare machine learning and Evolutionary algorithms ?" on their behavior to learn from previous and do best thing?

Is there any difference please mention it.

Answer (score 0):

Evolutionary algorithms are one class of strategies that can be used in machine learning, just like backpropagation and many others.

Evolutionary algorithms usually converge slowly because they make no use of gradient information. On the other hand they provide at least a chance to escape from local optima and find the global one.

Comment: Random search also provides the chance to "find the global optima" but this is not the reason to use it.

Comment: GA can perform parallel search and there is possibility to find global optima faster then random search. Also GA has information about quality of solution. This information gave the search process direction.